# Error "failed to proxy request: required metadata dapr-app-id not found" when trying to publish scheduled message to service bus

Tags: c#, azure, kubernetes, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I am working on writing an Azure Function which will publish a message to service bus and schedule the message to be ready in 15 minutes. I have implemented the Azure function on cluster and using DAPR pub sub to publish the message to a service bus topic. Below is the code I am using:

```
public static class TestFunc
{
[FunctionName("TestFunc")]
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
[HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = "TestFunc")] HttpRequest req,
[DaprPublish(PubSubName = "testSub", Topic = "testTopic")] IAsyncCollector<DaprPubSubEvent> pubEvent,            
ILogger log)
{

   log.LogInformation(" HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
   
   string uData = "Test Message";
   using var client = new DaprClientBuilder().UseGrpcEndpoint("http://127.0.0.1:50002").Build();
   var d = new Dictionary<string, object> ()
                    {
                       { "ScheduledEnqueueTime", DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMinutes(15).ToString()},
                            {"dapr-app-id", "someappid"}
                    };

    await client.PublishEventAsync("testSub", "testTopic", uData, d);
}
```

When I deploy the function on cluster and execute. I am getting error

> failed to proxy request: required metadata dapr-app-id not found.

I have tried to downgrade the Dapr. Client package to 1.9.0 from 1.12.0, but still getting same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the Dapr ID mentioned is correct and in your verify your DAPR component settings like below:-

Also, **`app-id`** is the name of the Function app. Refer this [*Github Document*](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dapr-extension/tree/master/quickstarts/dotnet-isolated) and this [MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-dapr?tabs=in-process,preview-bundle-v4x,bicep1&pivots=programming-language-csharp#dapr-enablement) on **`DAPR Function extension`**:-

***Deployed Dapr Functions from above Github Document:-***

[image]

Validate your ***Dapr component***:-

```yaml
apiVersion: dapr.io/v1alpha1
kind: Component
metadata:
  name: my-azure-function
spec:
  type: bindings.azurefunctions
  metadata:
    - name: dapr-app-id
      value: "my-azure-function-id"
```

Also, Validate the **`App Id`** you have mentioned in your Container App Environment:-

[image]

[image]

Also, Try to Run your Function App without Gprc endpoint:-

```cs
public static class TestFunc
{
    [FunctionName("TestFunc")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = "TestFunc")] HttpRequest req,
        [DaprPublish(PubSubName = "testSub", Topic = "testTopic")] IAsyncCollector<DaprPubSubEvent> pubEvent,            
        ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation("HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
        
        string uData = "Test Message";
        var d = new Dictionary<string, object>()
        {
            { "ScheduledEnqueueTime", DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMinutes(15).ToString() },
            { "dapr-app-id", "someappid" }
        };

        await pubEvent.AddAsync(new DaprPubSubEvent(uData, d));
        
        return new OkResult();
    }
}
```